# Call NtQuerySystemInformation in kernel-space

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, driver

I want to take SystemBasicInformation, SystemPerformanceInformation, SystemFileCacheInformation in kernel-space(from my nonPnP driver). But I can't call NtQuerySystemInformation in kernel-space, because it needs the user-space ntdll.lib.
Does anybody know the same NtQuerySystemInformation in kernel-space?

Comment: The documentation that says you should include `ntdll.lib` to use `ZwQuerySystemInformation` only applies to user mode programs.  Have you tried simply ignoring this?  AFAIK you don't normally need to specify library files to call kernel-mode functions.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking probably is [ZwQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

`Zw` indicates that it is for drivers, so you can always google some API with `Zw` prefix.

Also, why do you think that `ntdll.lib` means that API has to be called from user space? `NtQuerySystemInformation` should work as well, have you tried it, or just made a guess?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I try to call ZwQuerySystemInformation with include ntdll.lib, but it doesn't work because ntdll.lib is the user-space library. In WDK ntdll.lib is located in /um folder.